# Combining two region as one with boundaries: combining rectangle:

Tags: plotting, regions, mesh

If I have the following two regions:

```
r1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 10}]
r2 = Rectangle[{5, 0}, {15, 10}]
```

to combine them I can use,

```
RegionPlot[RegionUnion[r1, r2]]
```

which gives,

[image]

how can we add two regions with their boundaries still showing,
for example in the following,

[image]

I added the black line by myself.

Comment: E.g. `RegionPlot[{r1, r2}, PlotStyle -> LightBlue]` or even `RegionPlot[{r1, r2}, PlotStyle -> LightBlue, BoundaryStyle -> Black]`

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly there is a difference in showing two regions in plotting and joining them as one region.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration the comment by the author of the OP

`Not exactly there is a difference in showing two regions in plotting and joining them as one region.`

my suggested solution is the following:

```
Show[RegionPlot[RegionUnion[r1,r2]],Graphics[Line[Catenate@KeyValueMap[ConstantArray]@MapThread[Min,KeyIntersection[Counts/@{MeshCoordinates@r1, MeshCoordinates@r2}]]]]]
```

> [image: plot]

Commentary:

Given the two rectangles

```
r1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 10}];
r2 = Rectangle[{5, 0}, {15, 10}];
```

we can use [**`MeshCoordinates`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCoordinates.html) to get a list of their coordinates

```
l1 = MeshCoordinates@r1
l2 = MeshCoordinates@r2
```

Now, we have two lists of lists of the schematic form `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}..}`. In order to find the boundary of the rectangles, all we need to do is find those sublists from the above that are pairwise equal. This can be achieved as follows:

```
Catenate@KeyValueMap[ConstantArray]@MapThread[Min,KeyIntersection[Counts/@ {l1, l2}]]
```

Now, we have all we need to define the [**`Line`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) that represents the boundary. We wrap it with [**`Graphics`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)

```
line = Graphics[
   Line[Catenate@
     KeyValueMap[ConstantArray]@
      MapThread[Min, 
       KeyIntersection[
        Counts /@ {l1,l2}]]]];
```

Finally, as requested we use [**`RegionUnion`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html) to join the regions and then just show the boundary and joined regions

```
Show[RegionPlot[RegionUnion[r1, r2]], line]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a mesh region manually:

```
MeshRegion[
 Join[MeshCoordinates[r1], MeshCoordinates[r2]], { MeshCells[r1, 2], 
  Map[# + MeshCellCount[r1, 0] &, MeshCells[r2, 2], {2}]}]
```